# How to trigger a function in a specific node on treelist in Sencha Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I am a newbie to Sencha ExtJS. I want to add a tab when the user clicks on the University node. what should I use? I search a lot on the internet but could not find the answer which exactly addresses my issue.

```
 items: [{
    region: 'west',
    width: 200,
    reference: 'treelistContainer',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    itemId:'addNewTab',
    border: true,
    scrollable: 'y',
    bufferedRenderer: false,
    animate: true,
    rootVisible: false,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'treelist',      
        reference: 'treelist',
        itemId:'childpanel',
        store: {
                root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'Home',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
                        children: [{
                            text: 'Messages',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-inbox',
                            leaf: true
                        }]
                    }, {
                        text: 'Users',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-user',
                        children: [{
                            text: 'Tagged',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-tag',
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Inactive',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                            leaf: true
                        }]
                    }, {
                        text: 'Groups',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-group',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'Settings',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-wrench',
                        children: [{
                            name:'haseeb',
                            text: 'University',   
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-university',
                            leaf: true,
                            itemId: 'bar2', 
                           // cls='mycls'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            },
  },
      }],
```

Comment: Is tab.panel parent of treelist and you want to open other tab that you already define?

Comment: yes it is already define and working well but it work on all of the nodes of tree list i just want it tou call only on a specific node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw you are in **Modern Toolkit**. So you need first to find the right listener for treelist, [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.list.Tree.html#event-selectionchange)

```
listeners: {
        selectionchange : function(tree, rec) {
            if (rec.data.text === 'University')
            {

                //Call the tab from here
            }
        }
    },
```

Your code updated:

```
items: [{
region: 'west',
width: 200,
reference: 'treelistContainer',
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
itemId:'addNewTab',
border: true,
scrollable: 'y',
bufferedRenderer: false,
animate: true,
rootVisible: false,

items: [{
    xtype: 'treelist',      
    reference: 'treelist',
    itemId:'childpanel',

    listeners: {
        selectionchange : function(tree, rec) {
            if (rec.data.text === 'University')
            {
                //Call the tab from here

            }
        }
    },


    store: {
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
                    children: [{
                        text: 'Messages',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-inbox',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Users',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-user',
                    children: [{
                        text: 'Tagged',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-tag',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'Inactive',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Groups',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-group',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Settings',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-wrench',
                    children: [{
                        name:'haseeb',
                        text: 'University',   
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-university',
                        leaf: true,
                        itemId: 'bar2', 
                       // cls='mycls'
                    }]
                }]
            }
        },},}],
```

Comment: thank u  so much @gioalexiou this is the exactly what I want u are the best man <3

Comment: Have a good start with extjs sir! Be caureful with Modern and Classic toolkit when you read the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

You can **listen** to the `itemclick` event on the tree and check that text of clicked record is `University` i.e `record.text`, Like this:

```
     listeners:{
            itemclick:function(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
                if(record.data.text==='University'){
                   // your adding tab functionality comes here
                 }
          }
        }
```

Sample Code:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
   root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'Home',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
                        children: [{
                            text: 'Messages',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-inbox',
                            leaf: true
                        }]
                    }, {
                        text: 'Users',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-user',
                        children: [{
                            text: 'Tagged',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-tag',
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Inactive',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                            leaf: true
                        }]
                    }, {
                        text: 'Groups',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-group',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'Settings',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-wrench',
                        children: [{
                            name:'haseeb',
                            text: 'University',   
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-university',
                            leaf: true,
                            itemId: 'bar2', 
                           // cls='mycls'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    store: store,
     width: 200,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners:{
        itemclick:function(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
            if(record.data.text==='University')
                alert('University is clicked');
        }
    }
});

    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css"><!-- framework javascript --><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune-debug.js"></script>
```